# How to show activity indicator till data fetch and display in my collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have one collection view. I am fetching some data from an API and I am displaying it, in my collection view.Every thing works fine.But when I load my screen - first my screen is displayed and only after a delay of 5 to 6 seconds,  data is populated in my collection view. To solve this, I have did some  `dispatch main thread` to get the data quickly.

But some times based on user's phone's data connection , data is displayed late .For example if user has slow data connection , then it will take around 30 seconds (assumption ) to display the data in my collection view.

So , what I need is - how to show the activity indicator - till my data is displayed in my collection view.
I know how to create a dummy `Activity Indicator` and to display for 1 to 30 seconds.But i have to do this dynamically.

That means, I need to display the activity indicator, until data is displayed in my collection view. It should not be dependent upon user's data connection speed.

How to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
 var BTdata = [BTData]()
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 ListBusinessTypes()

}
// Values from Api for Business Types
    func ListBusinessTypes()
    {
        let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("access_token") as! String

        let headers = ["x-access-token": token]

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: “some url“)!,
                                          cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)

                let ErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Problem with internet connectivity or server, please try after some time", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                // add an action (button)
                ErrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                // show the alert
                self.presentViewController(ErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                {
                    let success = json["success"] as? Int

                    if(success == 1)
                    {

                        if let typeValues = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                                for item in typeValues
                                {
                                    self.BTdata.append(BTData(json:item))
                                }

                                self.collectionView1!.reloadData()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let message = json["message"] as? String

                        let ServerAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        // add an action (button)
                        ServerAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                        // show the alert
                        self.presentViewController(ServerAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes with your code and below is that

Use these as class variables

```
var actView: UIView = UIView()
var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var titleLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
```

And in your service calling function

```
showActivity(self.view, myTitle: "Loading...")
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error)  in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        if response != nil {
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                removeActivity(self.view)
                let ErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Problem with internet connectivity or server, please try after some time", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                // add an action (button)
                ErrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                // show the alert
                self.presentViewController(ErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }else {
                if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                    let success = json["success"] as? Int
                    if(success == 1) {
                        if let typeValues = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                                for item in typeValues {
                                    self.BTdata.append(BTData(json:item))
                                }
                                self.collectionView1!.reloadData()

                                removeActivity(self.view)
                            })
                        } else {
                            removeActivity(self.view)
                        }
                    } else {

                        removeActivity(self.view)

                        let message = json["message"] as? String
                        let ServerAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        // add an action (button)
                        ServerAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                        // show the alert
                        self.presentViewController(ServerAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                } else {

                    removeActivity(self.view)
                }
            }
        }
        })

    }

dataTask.resume()
```

The function to start animating

```
  func showActivity(myView: UIView, myTitle: String) {
    myView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    myView.window?.userInteractionEnabled = false
    myView.endEditing(true)
    actView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.frame.width, myView.frame.height)
    actView.center = myView.center
    actView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)

    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)
    loadingView.center = myView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = THEME_COLOUR
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);

    titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, loadingView.frame.height-20, loadingView.frame.width-10, 20)
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    titleLabel.text = myTitle
    titleLabel.font = IH_DELEGATE.BoldAppFontOfSize(10)

    loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    actView.addSubview(loadingView)
    loadingView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    myView.addSubview(actView)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

The function to stop animating

```
func removeActivity(myView: UIView) {
    myView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    myView.window?.userInteractionEnabled = true
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    actView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

**EDIT**
 Forgot to mention

```
let THEME_COLOUR = UIColor (red:0.188, green:0.682, blue:0.886, alpha:1)
```

Comment: i need to show the activity indicator color to red.And back ground view to white.

Comment: In your code i tried to change, but it din't change.How to change that color for both

Comment: color for both? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

To set indicator, create 2 methods for starting and stoping it. as given Below,

Create IBOutlet first

```
var activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

Create start method:

```
 func startIndicator()
{
    //creating view to background while displaying indicator
    let container: UIView = UIView()
    container.frame = self.view.frame
    container.center = self.view.center
    container.backgroundColor = CONTAINER_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR

    //creating view to display lable and indicator
    let loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 118, 80)
    loadingView.center = self.view.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor =  LOADING_VIEW_BACKGROUND_COLOR
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    //Preparing activity indicator to load
    self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(40, 12, 40, 40)
    self.activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    //creating label to display message
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 55,120,20))
    label.text = "Loading..."
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, loadingView.frame.size.height / 2)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    loadingView.addSubview(label)
    container.addSubview(loadingView)
    self.view.addSubview(container)

    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Create Stop method:

```
func stopIndicator()
{
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        ((self.activityIndicator.superview as UIView!).superview as UIView!).removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Then Call startIndicator in your viewdidload, above ListBusinessType method.
and then stop it when you get success and failure response from api.
This will help you. :)

NOTE: Change color as per your app theme.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But i dont know where should  i stop .I mean in my api method .So only i have posted my web service cell method.Can you please tell me under where i should stop the indicator in my code

Comment: Ok,write stop method above print(error) and let success = json["success"] as? Int

Comment: Have you got it? Say if you still don't get?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will try and let you know.